# Dotfuscator Causes TFS Build to Hang

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, tfsbuild, dotfuscator

I am having trouble getting builds to complete when they are set to run Dotfuscator on files. My environment is Visual Studio Professional 2012 paired with Team Foundation Server 2012, thus I am using Build Definitions and the Microsoft Team Foundation build architecture (build controller, build agents, etc).

My problem is that when I launch a build definition in Release config, which is set to run Dotfuscator Professional on my output files, the build hangs (either that or runs for so long that I have yet to see one complete). The log file shows that it is hanging during the build process template activity "Associate Changesets and Work Items", and task manager on my build server confirms that at this point Dotfuscator is running with huge CPU and memory requirements (around 50% CPU and I've seen near a gig of memory required). Here is the latter portion of the build log...

```
        Find Property Values
            CurrentLabel =
            LastLabel = 
            Result = (Collection)
            UpdateWorkItems = True
    Final Property Values
        Condition = True
Final Property Values
    Condition = True
```

The last lines are duplicated on purpose, this is exactly what the log reads. This is where the build hangs and Dotfuscator is still running on the build server.

And here's the interesting part, when I do a local build on the build server (right click on solution, click rebuild) the build runs great, done in under a minute Dotfuscator and all. This suggests to me that something is going on between Dotfuscator and Team Foundation Build. Possibly something to do with the Build Process Template and/or Build Agents? I'm not much of an expert on Team Foundation Build other than the work I have done getting to this point.

Any ideas on what I can do to get Dotfuscator to run faster or correctly (depending on the cause of my error)? All help is much appreciated.

Comment: How are you running Dotfuscator? From the command line or through the `Dotfuscate` MSBuild task?

Comment: Command line through a post build batch file. The command looks as such...

"dotfuscator [path to project].Obfuscate.Release.xml"

I included the path to dotfuscator executable as an environment variable on my build server to ensure this runs right.

Comment: Are you using the latest version? Also.. this is a bit silly, but have you ran Dotfuscator under that user account before? You may have to run Dotfuscator through the GUI once under that user account, in order to accept license agreements... though it should give an error for that, not just hang(unless you're using an older version)

Comment: That's an interesting idea! I'll give it a shot and see what I can find out. It probably isn't due to licensing, as through extended patience I have gotten a build to complete (100 minute run time!!!) with obfuscation. However there may be a snag there that is causing such a slowdown. I've also noticed that Dotfuscator is requiring up to a gig of RAM on the build server, is this completely out of the ordinary? Hopefully this new information sheds some more light.

Comment: Yes, ensure that your build server has enough memory. For large projects, a lot of memory may be consumed. For example, when obfuscating Dotfuscator with itself(dog fooding), we ensure the machine has 4G. It may work with less memory, but if it starts to page, it quickly runs away into thrashing. Especially since `ilasm` and `ildasm` consume a significant amount of memory as well as Dotfuscator itself.

Comment: That being said, in the past few updates, there have been some performance improvements in Dotfuscator. So, ensure you're running the latest version and ensure it has enough memory. 100 minutes seems like a long time to me. If it poses a problem to you though, you can contact [Dotfuscator Support](http://www.preemptive.com/support/dotfuscator-support). From there they can get further details and help pin point the problem and determine if it's something we can fix